# clip-path-property in CSS not truly clipping image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image that looks like the following:

[image]

Using the `clip-path` property in CSS I can clip out any part of this image as a circle.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         #profile-pic {
            clip-path: circle(20% at 50% 50%);
            width: 100%;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <img id="profile-pic" src="test.png" alt="Your Image">
   </body>
</html>
```

Which results in something like the following:

[image]

Now, suppose I wanted to put this inside of a `div` element which takes up 50% of the screen, I could do something like the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         #profile-pic {
            clip-path: circle(20% at 50% 50%);
            width: 100%;
         }
         div {
            width:50%;
            border: 10px solid black;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
         <img id="profile-pic" src="test.png" alt="Your Image">
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Which would render as follows.

[image]

As you can see the image dimensions are still taken from the *original* image and not the *circle-clipped* image.

I'd like to use only the diameter of the circle used in `clip-path` to fill up the div so I can really control the margins to what I need them to be, so something like the following:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Applying a clip-path does not change the element dimensions, it only changes which parts of it are shown. You will need to do the math and scale your image accordingly here.

Comment: What do you mean by scaling the image? How would that help with removing the parts outside the clipped region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) CSS property creates a clipping region that sets what part of an element should be shown. Parts that are inside the region are shown, while those outside are hidden."

Just like `visibility: hidden`, the clipped region is invisible but still affects layout as normal.

You can visually crop the image to its center by declaring the desired width for the container and applying `object-fit: none` & `aspect-ratio: 1` to the image.

At this point, `clip-path: circle()` and `border-radius: 50%` have the same effect. I included both just for demonstration (use Developer Tools to play with it.)

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  line-height: 0;
}

#profile-pic {
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  object-fit: none;
  clip-path: circle();
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img id="profile-pic" src="//i.stack.imgur.com/txOhB.png" alt="Your Image">
</div>
```

If you want to have a clipping region other than the center of the image, you can set the image as a background image and use `background-position` to position the targeted region into the clip path.

If you want a border around it, you'll need to have an additional wrapping container. Adjust the width of both containers to the appropriate size for the desired effect.

```css
div.border {
  border: 10px solid black;
  width: 105px;
}

div.image {
  width: 150px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background-image: url(//picsum.photos/200/300);
  background-position: 30% 75%;
  clip-path: circle(50% at 20% 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>

<p><img src="//picsum.photos/200/300"></p>
```

Comment: Your proposed answer doesn't use `clip-path` at all and that part of the CSS can be deleted. This doesn't work for me because I had strong reasons for using `clip-path`. Namely, `clip-path` allows me to center the circle anywhere I want on my image. In the OP I was centering it on the star, but I could have centered it somewhere else, for example clip-path: `circle(20% at 0% 50%);`. You can't do that with `border-radius` as far as I know.

Comment: @user32882 I've added an example using `background-image` and `background-position`